# How to get data out of the STL's const_iterator?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I have something that runs like this:

```
T baseline;
list<T>::const_iterator it = mylist.begin();
while (it != mylist.end()) {
    if (it == baseline) /* <----- This is what I want to make happen */
    // do stuff
}
```

My problem is that I have no idea how to extract the data from the iterator. I feel like this is a stupid thing to be confused about, but I have no idea how to do it.

EDIT : Fixed begin.end()

Comment: Your `while` has a problem: Use `mylist.end()`.

Answer (score 10):

Iterators have an interface that "looks" like a pointer (but they are not necessarily pointers, so don't take this metaphor too far).

An iterator represents a reference to a single piece of data in a container. What you want is to access the contents of the container at the position designated by the iterator. You can access the contents at position `it` using `*it`. Similarly, you can call methods on the contents at position `it` (if the contents are an object) using `it->method()`.

This doesn't really relate to your question, but it is a common mistake to be on the lookout for (even I still make it from time to time): If the contents at position `it` are a *pointer to an object*, to call methods on the object, the syntax is `(*it)->method()`, since there are two levels of indirection.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax to use an iterator is basically the same as with a pointer. To get the value the iterator "points to" you can use dereferencing with `*`:

```
 if (*it == baseline) ...
```

If the list is a list of objects you can also access methods and properties of the objects with `->`:

```
 if (it->someValue == baseline) ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
if (*it == baseline)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use *it to access the element pointed by the iterator. When you are comparing i guess you should use  if (*it == baseline)

Answer (score 1):

the std iterators overload the operator*(), this way you can access the referenced location the same way as if it was a pointer.

```
T const& a = *it;
```

Answer (score 0):

from what i know std iterators are not pointers, but are a thin wrapper around the actual pointers to the underlying individual data elements.

you can use 
`something=*it` 
to access an element pointed by the iterator.

The *it==baseline is a correct code for that kind of behaviour.

Also if you are dealing with collections from STL you can consider using functions such as `find_if`
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/